# How to access RFT installed on another remote machine?

Tags: java, rft

How can I access RFT installed on another remote machine through my machine?

Comment: Let's say remote m/c is rdcesx07057 and rft is installed on this machine.Now I want to access that RFT from my windows machine?

Answer (score 0):

What exactly you mean by  "I want to access ?"
Correct me  if I din't understand the question ..
"Are you trying to say you want to run RFT which is installed on  RDCESX07057 to be launched  on your local machine  and test the application installed locally " ?
If yes, then it is not be possible.

RFT can test applications which are accessible to the local machine only. So you can test application with RFT on RDCESX07057, which are installed/accessible on RDCESX07057.

What you can do (and probably you are alreaday doing ) is access the remote machine using  Remote Desktop and use RFT that way to test application installed on the remote machine. But RFT itself will not be accessible to you as a local application.

This is same as saying "we can't use the Windows Task Manager on a remote machine to  show us the processes on our local machine" .

Comment: Thanks!!If the application to be tested is also installed on the same machine RDCESX07057 and I want to test it using RFT which is also installed on that same machine So Is there any way to test it with my local machine without Remote desktop connection? Is it any how related to Rational Quality manager or adapter?

Comment: @krnitish You can launch test remotely using RQM, after starting the adapter on  RDCESX07057 machine. Disable the screensaver on the machine.

Comment: @AlessandroDaRugna Thank you! Can you describe in more detail?

Comment: @krnitish start from this doc http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/clmhelp/v4r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.rational.test.qm.doc%2Ftopics%2Fc_rft_adapter.html to our team the RFT/RQM adapter gave more troubles than benefits. The setup is very easy, just type the address of your RQM server. Configuring RQM to execute a couples of tests is overwhelming.